# The method pro(int, int) in the type prosedure_jsp is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java, jsp

this is my code

```
<%@ page import="static java.lang.System.out"%>
<%!
    void pro(int a, int b)
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 3;
        int luas;
        luas = a*b;

        out.print(a);
    }
%>
<%
    pro();
%>
```

and massage error is:

```
An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /prosedure.jsp
The method pro(int, int) in the type prosedure_jsp is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: It seems you don't really understand the concept of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a method that receives two input parameters (`int a` and `int b`) but you are not passing them anything.

You should put something like this:

```
<%
    pro(5,7);//5 and 7 are just an example
%>
```

Instead of what you have where you call `pro`.

Comment: I've tried your example, but there is no output on the screen (blank white)